# How to find,total memory/ram using by the postgresql database in Linux machine?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

When I execute `top -u postgres` or `ps -C postgres -o %cpu,%mem,cmd` in linux machine I am getting the list of postgres processors in my database machine. I need a consolidated %cpu and %ram usage by postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Some details for [caching in PostgreSQL and memory usage](http://raghavt.blogspot.de/2012/04/caching-in-postgresql.html) including disc caching.

Answer (score 0):

Try and test:

```
top -b -n 1 -u tomcat | awk 'NR>7 { cpusum += $9; ramsum += $10; } END { print cpusum, ramsum; }'
```

Comment: If it uses `top`, it counts the shared memory segment multiple times.

Comment: I have received output as  "247.5     418.1 ". What it means could you explain, please?

Comment: I have received output as  below.                                                           
                                                                                                            
  247.5          418.1                                                                                     
                                                                                                                 What it means could you explain, please?

Comment: First number is the total CPU usage, second one is the total memory used